# Angle of irregular quadrilaterel given length of every sides

Tags: geometry

[image]

The question needs to find the angle $\theta$ as in the image above.

I thought it was easy at first glance, but I couldn't find any solution after spending hours of time. Finding the area of the polygon might gain more insight into the problem, but it turns out I don't know how to find the area of this irregular polygon with only side lengths too.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the two vertices with a line segment to have a right triangle. Find the hypotenuse of the resulting right triangle using Pythagorean theorem. Solve the other triangle whose three sides you know and find the angles from there by the law of cosines.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple construction, we can arrive to this equation:
$$260^2-(200-x)^2=(160\cos \theta+80)^2$$ Where $x=160 \sin \theta$, which leads to
$$260^2-200^2+400\cdot 160 \sin \theta-(160 \sin \theta)^2=(160\cos \theta)^2+160^2\cos \theta +6400$$ or
$$5\sin \theta - 2\cos \theta=\frac{11}{32}$$
Can you solve the last equation?

[image]